# How to create an ACF shortcode with Repeater Field in WordPress functions.php?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

So I'm working on a testimonial and I want to create a shortcode using ACF Repeater Field and so I've found this [link](https://wp-types.com/forums/topic/display-acf-repeater-fields-via-shortcode-issue/) and wen I tried to apply it on my website it doesn't work.

Here is my ACF field structure

[image]

Here is my code in `functions.php`:

```
  function corridor_1_fn() {

   if( function_exists('have_rows') ) {

   ob_start();

   if( have_rows('_tl') ): 

    echo

    "<table class=''>
        <tr>
            <th>Status</th>
        <th>Quality</th>
        <th>Material</th>
    </tr>";

?>

    <?php while( have_rows('_tl') ): the_row(); ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="">
                <?php the_sub_field('_testimonial_content'); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="">
                <?php the_sub_field('_testimonial_author'); ?>
            </td>
            <td class="">
                <?php the_sub_field('_testimonial_img'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </table>

<?php endif;

     $content = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();
     return $content;

    }

}
add_shortcode('testimonials', 'corridor_1_fn');
```

So I just copied the code from the link and changed the field values for my testimonial custom field but doesn't work. Testimonials are located in Theme Options of my dashboard. What i'm missing here?

Comment: Try to use post id attribute: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ACF "_tl" is located on Options page, you don't have to use the code provided in a link ( `ob_start();` , `$content = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();`).

You just need to specify the page that contains this field in *have_rows* function, in your case - it is **Option** page. So:

```
if( have_rows('_tl','option') ): 
...
while( have_rows('_tl','option') ): the_row(); ?>
```

---

Instead of `echo` it is better to use this structure:

```
$out = '';
$out .= '<table class="">';
  $out .= '...';
$out .= '</table>';

return $out;
```